# iOS In App Purchases: Prices don't match selected App Store Connect tiers

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I've recently integrated in-app purchases into a project. I work with React Native / Expo (EAS) and `expo-in-app-purchases`. They work great - however for most of them, the prices don't match the selected price tier in App Store Connect.
I have only **consumable** IAPs with the following price tiers (Germany):

- Alternative Tier A (App Store Connect: €0.49 - Actually displayed price: €0.49)
- Tier 1 (App Store Connect: €0.99 - Actually displayed price: €1.09)
- Tier 2 (App Store Connect: €1.99 - Actually displayed price: €2.29)
- Tier 3 (App Store Connect: €2.99 - Actually displayed price: €3.49)

As you can see, only the price of the first tier (Alternative Tier A) gets correctly reported by StoreKit. It's not only a display bug, too: When buying something in the Sandbox, it also shows the wrong pricing during the actual purchase process.

Has anyone experienced this in the past? What can I do?

Comment: do you have any updates ?

Comment: @GuillaumeTheret Unfortunately not. I've opened a bug report with Apple. However, I suppose this is only a problem within the sandbox - it seems to use an old pricing table from pre-2021. We've published our app to review now and will simply hope the pricing table is correct in the live version.

Comment: Can you please keep me update, if the price table is correct in the live version. Thanks ! Hope this is only a sandbox issue

Comment: @GuillaumeTheret The app was just published. The prices are now correct in the live version, so it indeed seems like a sandbox bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little research, I've found some old posts in the Apple Developer forum saying this might be a sandbox bug. Even though I never found official confirmation of this, we've released our app to the App Store now. The prices are correct in the live version from the App Store. So this is indeed only a sandbox bug. The prices shown in App Store Connect will be the ones in the live app.